# can I hide certain HTML things using purely CSS?

Tags: html, css

I've got a bit of HTML code that looks like this:

```
<address>telephone no  <span>-</span>  Some Street 2  <span>-</span>  9999 ZZ Place <span>-</span>  Something else</address>
```

This bit of code is on a responsive website, and on a very small viewport I want to set the

```
Some Street 2  <span>-</span>  9999 ZZ Place <span>-</span>
```

to

```
display: none;
```

which would then only leave "Telephone no - Something else" visible.

Can I do this, using purely CSS, without touching/tweaking the HTML whatsoever? I know I can simply put a div with a class around the bit that I want to hide on a smaller viewport, but for certain reasons I'd really rather not.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: it's possible only by editing HTML output or using javascript

Comment: @MindaugasJakubauskas Incorrect. You don’t need to load a 32kb library to achieve that with JavaScript.

Comment: You cannot affect anything smaller than a full element using CSS. What are "certain reasons you'd really rather not"?

Comment: if I'd be willing to name those certain reasons, I'm sure I wouldn't have called them "certain reasons" to begin with ;) I did not think it would be possible though - but it's always possible that there's an obvious thing you don't know about, which is why I asked. :)

Comment: If I have understood correctly. I don't think what you're looking for is possible. But with some JavaScript it is. Will need to run some string functions to determine that particular section of the address. Otherwise I'd just recommend modifying the HTML slightly, but this would go against your preference. Instead of div, you could hide a span, using a span instead wouldn't interfere with the layout.

Comment: you MUST have to put 9999 zz.. in span or div or else how can you point them..??

Comment: as far as i can understand, the way(my idea, not sure) is to take your address content(string) and explode it and then divide by - symbol and take first and last child..but for this complicated js or jquery will be used..but still don't know why you don't want to use span or div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the parents pseudo `:after` element to show your desired text.

```css
@media (max-width: 920px) { /* <--- desired sceensize to change address */
    address {
        display: none;
    }

    div:after {
        content: 'telephone no - Some Street';
        font-style: italic;
    }

}
```

```html
<div>
    <address>telephone no  <span>-</span>  Some Street 2  <span>-</span>  9999 ZZ Place <span>-</span>  Something else</address>   
</div>
```

Comment: Well I mentioned that it's HTML code. I think it's fine to assume that it's just some static, non variable text.

Comment: @Mr Lister Well, my telephone number is always the same. ;-) Would be kind of crazy if it would change everday, don't you think?

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this. It suffers from a problem though: I'm not sure how to position the last line directly to the right of the first one, so I had to hardcode the width of the first (at 7em).
If anyone can come up with a better idea, I'm interested in hearing about it.

```css
@media (max-width: 30em) {
  address {
    height: 1.25em;
    line-height: 1.25;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 7em;
    text-indent: -7em;
  }
  address span {
    display: block;
  }
  address span:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: -7.5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<address>telephone no  <span>-</span>  Some Street 2  <span>-</span>  9999 ZZ Place <span>-</span>  Something else</address>
```

Comment: my bad..i did not resized..great answer..:)

Comment: Both this answer and the one from @DavidDomain are really good! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I like it, an inventive way to make CSS do something it doesn't do out of the box. +1

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
address {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    z-index: -999;
}
address:after {
    position: static;
     content: 'telephone no';
    display: block;
    width: 100px
        height: auto;
    font-size: 14px;
    white-space: nowrap;

}
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qr6nj5sa/)

although the answer has already been chosen, i do like to explode more on this topic personally. If anyone is interested, here's a non :after pseudo class way of doing it

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
address {
    width: 82px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: salmon;
}
}
```

[always look for others possible ways!](https://jsfiddle.net/qr6nj5sa/1/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no functionality in css to hide it as you have written in html, You have to put it between a div or any tag.